# An undiscovered island where the ecosystem is lethal to humans

Tags: story-identification

I read this book in the past 15 years, and it was a modern publication.

The book starts out following a TV reality show as they are about to maroon a group of young people on an undiscovered island.  The entire cast and crew are quickly killed live on TV within minutes of landing.

The rest of the book follows a US military and civilian investigation team as they attempt to explore the island, with fairly disastrous results.

Key themes in the book include: round crab-like creatures which roll on their edge and carry their young in spirals on their shells, the young are just as deadly as the adults; an intelligent orangutan or ape like creature found to be living in the wreckage of a crashed aircraft.

Comment: They marooned a group of people on an **undiscovered** island? How was that possible? Wouldn't somebody have to discover it before they could do that?

Comment: @user14111 the impression given is that no one knew about the island prior to the TV show landing people on it.

Comment: I suspect the word you're looking for is "remote" rather than "undiscovered"

Comment: I'm happy with the word I used.  I'm pretty sure I posted this on the scifi SE, not the English SE...

Comment: An island where the ecosystem is lethal to humans? Which part of Australia did they land on?

Comment: Sounds like Australia, everything will try to kill you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Fragment](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7346347-fragment) by Warren Fahy

> Aboard a long-range research vessel, in the vast reaches of the South
>   Pacific, the cast and crew of the reality show Sealife believe they
>   have found a ratings bonanza. For a director dying for drama, a
>   distress call from Henders Island—a mere blip on any radar—might be
>   just the ticket. Until the first scientist sets foot on Henders—and
>   the ultimate test of survival begins.
>
> For when they reach the island’s shores, the scientists are utterly
>   unprepared for what they find—creatures unlike any ever recorded in
>   natural history. This is not a lost world frozen in time; this is
>   Earth as it might have looked after evolving on a separate path for
>   half a billion years—a fragment of a lost continent, with an ecosystem
>   that could topple ours like a house of cards.

Reviews on goodreads mention the initial landing party being killed and "ape thing that can blend into any background and learn to read and talk in 20 minutes".

These excerpts can be about the crab-like creatures:

> “Those are disk-ants, as Nell here, who discovered them, calls them,”
>   Dr. Cato explained, looking over Pound’s shoulder.
>
> Nell zoomed in with an overhead camera to show a top view of one of
>   the disks on a monitor over the specimen chamber. The one she focused
>   on was waxy-white with a bruisy blue in the center. The “faceup” side
>   of the disk-ant looked like a pie sliced into five pieces. At the
>   center, a shark-toothed mouth grinned across the seams of two slices.
>   On either side of it were dark eyes anyone could take for buttonholes.
>
> Facedown ants were embossed with three spiraling horns radiating from
>   the center on their upper sides.
>
> ...
>
> “When these ants are not rolling, they can walk on either flat side
>   and carry food on top. When rolling, they can carry food on both
>   sides, feeding themselves and their offspring at the same time.”

Comment: Can you stop spamming the front page with rather redundant edits please, if you _must_ do them at least spread them out so new answers and questions are visible.